# Flutter dart Map with multiple keys for very same value

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

Is there any kind of collection to declare a map with multiple keys linked to the very same value ?

I want the map to be initialized at the same time that it is declared. Ideally something like:

```dart
MyMap<String, String> mymap = {['red', 'blue', 'green'] : 'Rock', ['pink', 'yellow' ...etc}
```

So far I found [Multimap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/quiver.collection/Multimap-class.html) in the documentation but it seems that its one key for multiple value, and on top of that I have a lot of trouble for implementing since that despite the documentation there is 0 example given.

Here my try so far:

```dart
static Iterable mylist = ['red', 'blue', 'green']; // I want to associate these strings to 'Rock'
static Iterable mylist = ['pink', 'yellow', 'cyan']; // I want to associate these strings to 'Funk'
static Multimap<String,String> okayboomer = Multimap.fromIterable(mylist);//, {K key(dynamic element), V value(dynamic element)});
```

And then whenever I access okayboomer['red'] I would get 'Rock'.

I was also thinking about [HashMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html)

Any help strongly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need any special data structure; a normal `Map` can have multiple keys for the same value, and you just need a helper function to make initializing it more convenient:

```dart
Map<String, String> makeMyMap(Map<List<String>, String> map) {
  var newMap = <String, String>{};
  for (var entry in map.entries) {
    var keyList = entry.key;
    for (var key in keyList) {
      newMap[key] = entry.value;
    }
  }
  return newMap;
}
```

and then you should be able to do:

```dart
var mymap = makeMyMap({
  ['red', 'blue', 'green'] : 'Rock',
  ['pink', 'yellow', 'cyan']: 'Funk',
});
```

Note that the above `Map` would work for lookups, and if you *mutated* values in the map, the related keys would still refer to the same object.  If, however, you need to *replace* values in the map, related keys would continue referring to the old object.  If you need to do that, you would need to add a level of indirection around the values.  For example:

```dart
class Wrapped<T> {
  Wrapped(this.value);
  T value;
}

var map = <String, Wrapped<String>>{};
map['red'] = map['blue'] = map['green'] = Wrapped('Rock');
map['red'].value = 'Funk';
print(map['blue'].value); // Prints: Funk
```

You could derive a class from [`DelegatingMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/DelegatingMap-class.html) to automatically unwrap values when using `operator []` and to automatically update existing `Wrapped` objects for `operator []=`.

Comment: This is a very nice answer but one reason why I want to initialize as I declare the map is to create the map at compile time and not at runtime. Is there any way to tweak your code to allow this ? PS: I like very much both ways you explained.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jamesdlin's answer, you should be able to just assign duplicate values to multiple keys. However, depending on your use case, this may not work for you. If you want to change the value associated with the key 'red', it will not update the listings associated with 'blue' and 'green'

If this type of integrity is important to you, I would store all of your values in a list, or a secondary map, and then store references to them in the primary map. That way, if you update any of the keys, it will change the values for all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want the map to be initialized at the same time that it is declared, you can simply do it this way

```
 Map<List<String>,dynamic> x = {
  ['red', 'blue', 'green']:"ROCK",
  ['pink', 'yellow', 'cyan']:"FUNK"
 };
```

And then access the values by iterating over keys and the List,

```
print(x[x.keys.firstWhere((value)=>value.contains("red"))]);
```

Comment: Note that with this approach, you would lose most of the advantages of using a `Map` (such as constant-time lookup for a `LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: yes exactly what I was thinking and on top of that a bit lengthy to retrieve. Still interesting idea